# Synology chat incoming webhooks

Tags: bash, shell, curl, webhooks, synology

I bought a Synology DiskStation and installed Synology chat (Version 2.4.0) on it.

According to [Synology's documentation](https://kb.synology.com/en-eu/DSM/help/Chat/chat_integration?version=7) it should be possible to send data (e. g. a text) in Synology chat to a channel with **incoming webhooks**.

So I created an incoming webhook and wrote a shell-skript with curl to send text to my channel:

```
curl -k -X POST 'https://IP-ADDRESS:5001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.Chat.External&method=incoming&version=2&token=THIS-IS-MY-TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "This is a test"}'
```

However, when I execute the skript, it throws this error:

> {"error":{"code":120,"errors":{"name":"payload","reason":"required"}},"success":false}

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what does the log at the server side reveal about the error when you execute this curl command? Have to tried exploring the server logs?

Comment: As far as I know there is no server log for this function, I executed the command manually. It gaves me just the result which is the error.

Comment: Well as per http standard error code, 120 is an informational code specifying that server has begun the processing of the command. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#information_responses

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the payload but i don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To post via curl this modification to your command worked for me: `curl -X POST 'https://IP-ADDRESS:5001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.Chat.External&method=incoming&version=2&token=THIS-IS-MY-TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 'payload={"text": "This is a test"}'`

Comment: Instead of just pasting a long command, it would be helpful to point out what you changed and why.